# Intermittent NGINX error: client sent invalid chunked body

Tags: java, http, nginx, http-1.1

I am running into a weird issue, where NGINX is intermittently returning 400 with error log

> 2018/08/15 07:08:38 [error] 3794#3794: *961526 client sent invalid chunked body, client: 10.$$.$$.$$, server: $$.api.$$.com, request: "PUT /v2/$$ HTTP/1.1", host: "$$.api.$$.com"

When does this error come?

A little context about how I am making the request:

I am making http call using org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.

The problem is that issue is not consistent. I tried from my local and the code always works, but when we run the same command from jenkins, it fails for a particular payload. I tried with the same java version on my local and it always works. More weird is the fact that sometimes even from the same jenkins it worked.

Does anybody have any pointers?

Comment: We're running into similar issues. Have you been able to resolve yet? Are you using Netty in any part of your pipeline? And do you have versions for both the client servers and the host servers (and what they are server they are running...)? Our instinct is that it is Netty, and we want to file something with project reactor...your input would be useful to triage

Comment: Yes, as @RankWeis suggests, the versions of nginx, apache http client+core, java  and netty (if applicable) may be relevant.

Comment: @RankWeis please checkout my answer, Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I forgot to update this answer.
my issue turned out to be setting incorrect content-Type

Changing from

```
entity.addBinaryBody("zipFile", zipFileStream, contentTypeApplicationZip, zipFileName);
```

to

```
entity.addPart("zipFile", new ByteArrayBody(IOUtils.toByteArray(zipFileStream), zipFileName));
```

Solved the issue.